# Windows 7 - use PAC file for all network traffic

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy

Is there a way to set up Windows 7 so that any and all network traffic is forced to use a PAC file? I currently can access the internet at work through browsers which use a PAC file, but things like installers (the ones that also download stuff) are unable to access it with the error `the target machine actively refused the connection`. Most places I've looked at specify how to set it up for a single IP address, but I need to use a PAC file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No is the simple answer. You can set all default *HTTP* traffic to go through a proxy (and a few others) but in the end it's the program's decision whether to use the system default setting or not.

Comment: How do you do it for all HTTP traffic?

Comment: Control Panel => Internet Options => Connections => LAN settings

Comment: Ah. I already have that set..

Comment: That's all you can set. The only alternative is a transparent proxy that intercepts all outbound traffic. Best done on the router but can be done on your local machine if needed (it's just more complex)